# Fibonacci inequality proved by induction.

Tags: proof-verification, fibonacci-numbers

I need to show that $F_{n+2} \geq 2F_{n}$ for all $n \geq 1$.

For n=1, $F_3=2=2(F_1)=2$.Checks out.

Now for the inductive hypothesis, assume for some n that $F_{n+2} \geq F_{n}$. 
We need to show that $F_{n+3} \geq 2F_{n+1}$.

Here is where I run into trouble.

$F_{n+3}=F_{n+2}+F_{n+1}$, but it seems clear to me that $F_{n+2}>F_{n+1}$, giving the desired conclusion.

How can I use the inductive hypothesis here? it feels like I really don't need it.

Comment: Well, I guess you can use induction to probe that $F_{n+1}>F_{n}$, not that it is difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's kind of a silly problem as it is so obviously true ... induction is total overkill .... but you are asked to use induction, so induction it will be.

Here is the thing to do: since the Fibonacci sequence is recursively defined on *two* earlier entries, you need a base of *two* cases, and for the inductive hypothesis for the step, assume that the statement holds for *both* $n+1$ and $n+2$

In other words, first show that $F_3 \ge 2F_1$ *and* that $F_4 \ge 2F_2$

Then, assume that $F_{n+1} \ge 2F_{n-1}$ *and* $F_{n+2} \ge 2F_n$, and use that to show that $F_{n+3} \ge 2F_{n+1}$

Comment: So instead of doing a base case n=0 I would do n=0 and n=1?

Comment: @Jungleshrimp n=1 and n=2, but yes, *two* base cases, so that you can then recurse/induce over two previously established cases